# pandas groupby with value counts

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['ant','ant','cherry', 'dog', 'ant'], 'B':['animal','animal', 'fruit', 'animal', 'animal'], 'C':['small','small','small', 'big', 'small']})

     A        B       C
0   ant    animal   small
1   ant    animal   small
2   cherry  fruit   small
3   dog    animal   big
4   ant   animal    small
```

I need to do a groupby so that the result is in the following form.

```py
     A        B       C    Count_A
0   ant    animal   small    3
1   cherry  fruit   small    1
2   dog    animal   big      1
```

I have tried the following:

```py
s = df.groupby(['A','B','C'])['A'].count()
```

The result is what I needed. However, I am unable to do any slicing on it since, all columns 'A','B' and 'C' have become the index now. the method `.reset_index()` also does not work. I get a value error `ValueError: cannot insert A, already exists`.

Would anyone be able to help me regarding this?

Comment: `df.groupby(['A','B','C']).size()
` and your code work for me

Comment: Use `df.groupby(['A','B','C']).size().reset_index(name='Count_A')`

Comment: ok. thanks. That helped.